# InversifyJS not injecting dependencies in nested classes

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am trying to use InversifyJS for dependency injection in my typescript app.  Everything works perfectly when I follow the simple examples given in the documentation.  However, the dependencies don't get injected in to classes that are lower in the dependency chain.  Hopefully this example will make what I am trying to say more clear.  I removed as much boilerplate as I could:

EmployeeFactory.ts

```
@injectable()
class EmployeeFactory {
    create(employeeName: string): Employee {
        /*
         * I think my error comes from the use of
         * the new keyword right here. Not sure though.
         */
        return new Employee(employeeName);
    }
}
```

Company.ts

```
@injectable()
class Company {
    @inject('EmployeeFactory') private employeeFactory: EmployeeFactory;

    public getEmployees() {
        return [
            this.employeeFactory.create('Alice'),
            this.employeeFactory.create('Bob')
        ]
    }

}
```

Employee.ts

```
@injectable()
class Employee  {
    @inject('EmployeeFactory') private employeeFactory: EmployeeFactory;
    constructor(readonly name: string) {

    }

    public getBoss(): Employee {
        //TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
        return this.employeeFactory.create("Boss man")
    }
}
```

And then this is the code I run to get the error

```
import { Container } from "inversify";

let myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<EmployeeFactory>("EmployeeFactory").to(EmployeeFactory);
myContainer.bind<Company>('Company').to(Company);
myContainer.bind<Employee>('Employee').to(Employee);

let oscorp: Company = myContainer.get<Company>('Company');

let employees: Employee[] = oscorp.getEmployees();
console.log('employees', employees);
// PRINTS: employees [ Employee { name: 'Alice' }, Employee { name: 'Bob' } ]

let boss = employees[0].getBoss(); 
console.log('boss', boss);
```

So my question is this: How do I get EmployeeFactory to be injected in to the Employee class without having "myContainer" throughout my app? I'm sure I am missing something crucial about InversifyJS, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: Display an error what you receive. What I see from the glance you should decouple Container presentations of another objects. After applying of decorators the inversifyjs is responsible for object creation of the classes.

Comment: Do not use it this way.` return new Employee(employeeName);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that class `Employee` is created just with operator `new`, not with inversifyJS. So, you creating new instance just by JS, without any dependency injection.

If you want just make your code work, you can simply rewrite your code to smth like

EmployeeFactory.ts

```js
@injectable()
class EmployeeFactory {
    create = (employeeName: string): Employee => {
        return new Employee(this, employeeName);
    }
}
```

Employee.ts

```js
@injectable()
class Employee  {
    constructor(
        private _employeeFactory: EmployeeFactory,
        readonly name: string,
    ) {}

    public getBoss(): Employee {
        return this._employeeFactory.create("Boss man")
    }
}
```

But if you want to make it the inversify way, then you need to use Factory Injection:
https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/factory_injection.md

Then you need to change your code in bindings to

```js
myContainer.bind<Company>('Company').to(Company);
myContainer.bind<Employee>('Employee').toConstructor(Employee);
container.bind<interfaces.Factory<Employee>>('Factory<Employee>').toFactory<Employee>((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return (name: string) => {
        const EmployeeConstructor = context.container.get<Employee>('Employee');
        return new EmployeeConstructor(name);
    };
});
```

Company.ts

```js
@injectable()
class Company {
    @inject('Factory<Employee>') private employeeFactory: (name: string) => Employee;

    public getEmployees() {
        return [
            this.employeeFactory('Alice'),
            this.employeeFactory('Bob')
        ]
    }

}
```